# Why can we use useState to display loading state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I have seen people use useState in async await functions to handle loading state during fetch requests.

If we look at the code below. Loading state changes as expected, i.e. you hit submit and `loggingIn` will be set to true and after the login function finishes executing, `logginIn` is set to false. This means you can use `logginIn` to display a spinner after the user hit the login button.

I want to understand properly why this works? According to the React doc, `A state variable’s value never changes within a render, even if its event handler’s code is asynchronous.`(
[https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot#state-over-time](https://stackoverflow.com)). Based on this, I would have thought that React would execute the two `setLogginIn` instances together.

Or does this work because React "respects" async await and schedules the first `setLogginIn` before `await login(email, password)` finishes and the second `setLogginIn` after? But then on the other hand, I though state only changes with a re-render, and I would think a event handle (like handleSubmit) can only trigger a re-render once?

```
const [logginIn, setLogginIn] = useState(false);

async function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      setLogginIn(true);
      await login(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        setLoginError(error.message);
      }
    } finally {
      setLogginIn(false);
    }
  }
```

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleSubmit` is awaiting `login()`, but React itself is not awaiting `handleSubmit`.

This statement is executed:

```
setLogginIn(true);
```

Which queues a state update.  That update will be performed, and the component will be re-rendered, when the thread (JavaScript is single-threaded) is next available to process these operations.

Then this statement is executed:

```
await login(email, password);
```

Presumably `login()` internally performs an asynchronous operation which can be offloaded from the thread.  For example, an HTTP operation being handled by the browser (which is *not* single-threaded).

While JavaScript waits for the host system to complete this operation, it's available to do other things.  So, now being idle, it's available to continue with the results of any previously queued asynchronous operations.

(At this point it's worth noting that asynchronous operations are not *always* Promises.  That is, you can't `await` the state update because React doesn't expose it as a Promise.)

So the state update is processed and the component is re-rendered.  JavaScript is now idle again.

Then at some later time, the host system completes the awaited asynchronous operation (e.g. an HTTP request) and notifies JavaScript of the result.  This operation is now complete:

```
await login(email, password);
```

And the code within the `handleSubmit` method continues to execute.

Comment: Thank you @David! To check my understanding: `setLogginIn(true)` triggers a re-render before and not at the same time as `setLogginIn(false)`, because while the awaited statement `login()` is being executed, Javascript thread is free can update the `logginIn` to `true` and perform a re-render.

This is helpful. Before I just assumed that when React looks at `handleSubmit`, it will queue all state updates together whether they are coded in lines before or after an awaited operation. (Because I've read many times that there's no guarantee that states are updated immediately.)